# How to take user input when i installing a android app on device?

Tags: android

I want to take a user input like some text when the apk is installed first time in a device and want to use this input as a very use full information

Comment: Be clear , What you want to do ?

Comment: get the value from e editText and store it using sharedPreference and use it from there the next time.

Comment: @RajeevNB I want that when one users download my app and want to install then a popup will arise which take a number input and if user give the input and press ok then my app install on his device other will not

Comment: @AndroSelva Please be specific i can not understand your opinion

Comment: Oops. I don't think you can control installation and uninstall. Sorry!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want that when one users download my app and want to install then a popup will arise which take a number input and if user give the input and press ok then my app install on his device other will not

This is not possible. Your app's code cannot run before it is installed, and it cannot even run automatically after installation. You will first get control when the user launches one of your activities.